# file transfer using SCP

Tags: scp

I want to transfer my file to other system using scp. It is a tar.bz2 folder having just 300 MB size but it is taking 6 hours to transfer and still 49% complete.. Now it is disconnected at 49%. I want to restart,is there any command using which it can be restarted, or using which I can transfer faster.

Comment: You might also have an underlying network problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rsync` might be the tool for you to use. It does need to be installed on both sides of the transfer. Here is a sample command shamelessly copied from [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20860896/is-there-a-way-to-continue-broken-scp-secure-copy-command-process-in-linux):

```
rsync --partial --progress --rsh=ssh local_file user@host:remote_file
```